# Refactor an interface to use HttpWebRequest which currently uses a generic System.ServiceModel.ClientBase

Tags: .net, wcf, httpwebrequest, x509

Im currently working on the refactoring of an interface (.net wcf windows service) which sends data to a java based axis service.

I would like the new reservation to be able to send a piece of xml using http web request to the url that is currently configured in the app.config from the wcf based interface.

So far i have captured the logging from the old interface, and created a new interface, able to post that data to a url. Basicly, this works. The response from the axis service is that the token could not be validated:

```
<faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; 
nested exception is:    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: 
The security token could not be authenticated or authorized</faultstring>
```

In the old interface, the binding information in the app.config looks like this:

```
  <endpoint address="https://beta.<<>>.com/ws/services/ReservationService"
    behaviorConfiguration="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MutualCertificateBinding"
    contract="ReservationServiceContract" name="" kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
    <identity>
      <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="27 38 6f 86 b6 67 45 be 1a 60 60 ef 1f 7c 73 d6 5b 1b 7d 7f"
        isChainIncluded="false" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

Im using the following code to send the request to the web service:

```
    private string HandleHttpPost(string url, UTF8Encoding encoding, string xmlMsg)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        string request = textBoxRequestPrefix.Text + xmlMsg;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(request);

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        webRequest.ContentType = textBoxRequestContentType.Text;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSoapAction.Text))
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", textBoxSoapAction.Text);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxCertificatePath.Text))
        {
            X509Certificate2 xc = new X509Certificate2(textBoxCertificatePath.Text);
            webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(xc);
        }

        Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        webResponse.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

Which tells me that a x509 certificate is being used. My question is, how can i make the HttpWebRequest work?

Addition: the custom binding configuration:

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="MutualCertificateBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
  <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
    includeTimestamp="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
    requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
    <secureConversationBootstrap />
  </security>
  <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  </textMessageEncoding>
  <context protectionLevel="None" />
  <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" maxBufferSize="65536" />
</binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: Why would you expect HttpWebRequest to work? The server is apparently using WS-Security. Also, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Im not sure if im right, however, i dont see why ws-security would not work together with HttpWebRequest. In the end, both wil do a http post, right?

The actual reason is the implementation (at a functional level) of the interface. We want to rewrite the interface and have a framework ready to build the messages that we need, however it expects to HttpWebRequest to send the message.

Comment: Another comment, the other party is not able to provide a wsdl file therefore im not able to test the interface using an application like soapui.

Comment: Sorry, you should question that. The exception is clearly from Apache, which very certainly supports WSDL. They may not be able to provide the WSDL online, but they can certainly get it and email it to you. Also, WS-Security is too complex to try to create "by hand". This will not be a simple "envelope".

Comment: Did you have working solution with WCF? What was the configuration of custom binding?

Comment: Im posting the custom binding configuration.